# RRN model output smaller than expected data. How Can I improve it to be closer to the actual one?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a model to forecast a time series based on other metric different than the expected output.

I fed my model with an array (X) composed by 200 time steps and I try to predict other array (Y) just one step in the future, which is supposed to be a quite easy problem.
Train_X.shape = (61463, 200, 1), Train_y.shape = (61463,)

My model, using Sequential KERAS' api is:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=30,kernel_size=4,
                                  strides=2,padding='valid',
                                  input_shape=(n_steps,n_features)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100,return_sequences=True,dropout=0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100,return_sequences=True,dropout=0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(50,activation='exponential')))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

The model predicts the waveform of the Y array quite good. Although the values are smaller than the real ones. That's why I add and exponential Dense layer, because I've read is useful when output and input have different scales.

I attach the obtained prediction, the actual values and the inputs of the model

[Result of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzP2q.png)

I also compare the obtained and actual values to see the issue I have.

[Actual vs Predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXz6j.png)

Please help me to solve this problem. I've tried hundreds of different solutions but none work.

Comment: Have you tried target scaling?

Comment: Do you mean if I have normalize the data? I have tried to apply a StandardScaler to both inputs and outputs, but output still has bigger values.